# Axis breaks with integer and non-integer numbers: how to suppress the zero decimals of the integer numbers without excluding the non-integer numbers?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I’m working in a graph where the axis breaks include integer and non-integer numbers.
For illustration purposes consider the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = 0:10, y = 0:10)) +           
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, 2.5)) + 
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, 2.5))
```

[image]

Ggplot is plotting the breaks as: `0.0, 2.5, 5.0, 7.5, 10.0`
However I wished that the integer numbers (0, 5 and 10) would appear without the zero decimal, and at the same time I still want keep the non-integer numbers (2.5 and 7.5).
Considering the example above, I wished that the axis breaks would appear as: `0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10`

Is it possible to do this?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x=0:10,y=0:10))+           
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,10,2.5), labels=c(0,2.5,5,7.5,10))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,10,2.5), labels=c(0,2.5,5,7.5,10))
```

with output 
[image]

Comment: or to calculate the labels, `format(seq(0, 10, 2.5), drop0trailing = TRUE)` or maybe better, `labels = function(x){format(x, drop0trailing = TRUE)}`